# Laravel - symlink public folder

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, symlink

I am trying to redirect to the "public" laravel directory.

My path looks like this: "/domains/app.naviapp.world/naviapp" and I want to redirect it to "/domains/app.naviapp.world/public_html"

I try this:

```
ln -s naviapp/public/ public_html
```

Unfortunately, it does not work

Comment: What doesn't work?  Is the symlink pointing correctly at public?  Is the web server giving an error?

Comment: @Devon 403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied!

Comment: Check the web server log to see why you are receiving a 403.

Comment: If you're using apache webserver make sure you are using the FollowSymLinks option

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache like @apokryfos said you need to enable `FollowSymlinks`

But you must also create all symlinks with full paths from `/` or a 403 will be returned.